# Weird corruption of cached .pyc bytecode

Tags: python

Firstly, I cannot provide a MCVE for this problem, so please bear with me.

Install is Python 2.7.9 on Windows 7.

Some background: It seems that Python caches .pyc files in memory, *even between interpreter sessions*, although I've not been able to find any information about this. This can be seen (I think) by the fact that when I start a GTK application after a fresh boot, it takes around 6s to load, thereafter it takes <1s.

This application is a test sequencer which runs the tests in a separate thread to avoid blocking the GTK main loop. I came across a strange issue yesterday whereby, if the command window is forcibly closed at a certain point whilst the test thread is running, subsequent runs will raise an exception when a dict is being created, such as this:

```
TypeError("unhashable type: 'cts: unknown\n  picker: [None|float|boolean|callable]         \n  pickradius: unknown\n  rasterized: [True | False | None]
\n  sketch_params: unknown\n  snap: unknown\n  transform: :class:'~matplotl'",)
```

The actual 'type' inside the single quotes varies, and can be anything at all. 
The actual dict definition is more complex, but will still fail in this case:

```
comptypevalidity = {'EQ':True,
                    'NE':False,
                    'GT':False,
                    'LT':False,
                    'GE':False,
                    'LE':False,
                    'GELE':False,
                    'GTLT':False,
                    'GELT':False,
                    'GTLE':False,
                    'LOG':True}
```

You will see that I'm not trying to create a Dict key out of some esoteric object, but simply strings. Most of the time it works, it's only in this case where the bytecode appears to have been corrupted that it fails.

Now, I'm fairly certain that this is a CTypes / pointer type problem, where a DLL is not being properly closed.

The bit I'm struggling with is the  fact that the only way I can make it work again is by forcing recompilation of the `.pyc` in which the exception is being raised, by deleting it. I've done a file compare of 'good' and 'bad' files to see if somehow they are being corrupted on the HDD, but as expected they are identical.

The fix is running Python with the `-B` flag, so that no `.pyc` are written, and this seems to also force the interpreter to re-compile, rather than using a version cached in RAM.

So, my question is twofold:

Is it true that Python caches to RAM, if not - what am I seeing here? How can a corrupted `.pyc` persit across interpreter sessions

Can I force Python to **not** cache these files?

Comment: The reason why your application starts much faster the second time you run it is that Linux has a [buffer cache](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/buffer-cache.html). I would not jump to conclusions this quickly,  the exception text and your description do not imply to that what you are facing is a lower-level problem. More information on the exception - like a traceback and information on the object that you try to hash (e.g. by using it as a key in a dictionary) would be useful.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned, this is Windows. Although, I'm sure that Windows has a similar cache. Would this persist for many hours, with many intervening disk-reads, though? I've added info on the dict definition - the keys are all strings. Will try and get a fuller traceback.